# async await method comparison

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm getting started with the TPL, and have got a question with regards to the significance of calling await inside the called method marked as async, versus just awaiting the calling function that calls a method that isn't maked as async.

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TBox.Text += await WebClientDownloader();
    TBox.Text += await WebClientDownloadWithAwait(); 
}

private async static Task<string> WebClientDownloadWithAwait()
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        return await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com");
    }
}

private static Task<string> WebClientDownloader()
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        return wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Is there a difference? They appear to perform equally.

Comment: Is it me or awaiting the result from DownloadStringTaskAsync would return the actual respons instead of Task<string>? In that case your code wouldn't build.

Comment: @linkerro If you return anything from `async` method, it's returned wrapped in a `Task`. That's how `async ` works.

Comment: Still, you're wrapping it in a Task for no good reason.

Comment: @linkerro You can't *not* wrap it in a `Task`, if you want to use `async`. That's the good reason. If the method returned the result directly, it would have to be synchronous. And in this case, that would mean it would block the UI thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is when is `Dispose()`called. If you don't use `await`, then the `WebClient` is `Dispose()`d right after you start the download and *before* the download finishes. It may work in your specific case, but it's not guaranteed to work, so you should definitely use `await` here.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Assuming I wasn't calling something that  implements IDisposable, they would be equal?

Comment: Yes, if you didn't have any code in `finally` that executes after your `return` (which you do now thanks to the `using`), the two versions would be the same. The only difference would be that using `await` would be less efficient.